# 'slideDown' effect with jquery doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `slideDown` effect with jquery effect, however it doesnt appear to work. I think it is because the element on which I am trying to implement the effect is already visible on the screen. I think it may be required to be hidden before it can show up a slideDown effect but I am unsure as to how to implement that. Any guidance on this appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript and HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the CSS property "display: none;" to your element. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kUkRU/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("div#id").hide().slideDown();
});
```